# In excel 365, finding duplicate data in 2 seperate sheets and then copy an adjacent cells data

Tags: excel, office365, vlookup, matching, autofill

I am stuck trying to figure this out. I am using Excel 365 and I need a formula for a cell that looks at the data in the first sheet's column 5, and matches column one of the 4th sheet, and then once the match is found it auto-fills data into column 3 of the 4th sheet that is found in column 1 in the first sheet.  SOUNDS confusing. So I added a screen shot and will re-describe the issue below:

[image]

In the image above, the top sheet is the P320 sheet. The Payroll is entered and I already have the name auto-filled already. Columns 3,4, 5, 6 are entered manually. Column 1, "Payroll", and column 5, "Issued Serial" are the 2 columns in question.

The second sheet in the picture is the 4th sheet "New Inventory". What is happening is that there will be a list of serial numbers entered as well as the caliber and size. The 4th column, "Assigned Payroll" is the 3rd in question.

What I need is that in sheet one, "P320", when the data is entered and the replacement serial number is entered, the payroll of the individual being assigned to that serial number will automatically show up in column 4, Assigned Payroll, in the "New Inventory" sheet on the same line the matching replacement serial number is.

Man, I am so sorry if this is confusing. It's even confusing me the way I am writing it.

Assigned Payroll in "New Inventory" needs to be auto-filled by the payroll found in "P320" sheet column one if and only if the new serial numbers match in both sheets, columns "Issued Serial" and "Serial #".  Maybe that helps? :)

Thank you so much for your guys' help!

Dennie

Comment: should this line  "auto-fills data into column 3 of the 4th sheet" be  auto-fills data into column 4 of the 4th sheet?

Comment: =IFERROR(INDEX('P320'!A:A,MATCH(A2,'P320'!E:E,0)),"NO MATCH")  in New Inventory D2 and drag down for however many rows? You could limit range rather than use whole columns

Answer (score 0):

If you have the data in `Worksheets("P320")` as follows:

[image: Illustrative sample of data in Sheet P320]

You would enter in `Range("D2")`  in `Worksheets("New Inventory")` the following formula and drag it down as many rows as is necessary:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX('P320'!A:A,MATCH(A2,'P320'!E:E,0)),"NO MATCH")
```

The result is as shown here:

[image: Formula result in sheet New Inventory]

The following is looking for the position of the Serial # in Column A of `Worksheets("New Inventory")` in Column E of `Worksheets("P320")`

```
 MATCH(A2,'P320'!E:E,0)
```

This returns either `#N/A` if not found or the row number where found in Column E.

If a match was found the use of `INDEX` on Column A in `Worksheets("P320")`, with the position of the row match for the Serial # in the step before, will return the value in the same row of Column A.

```
INDEX('P320'!A:A,MATCH(A2,'P320'!E:E,0))
```

If there had been no match found in the prior step the remaining `#N/A` is handled by the wrapping `IFERROR()` where you can specify what to return if an error is detected.

In this case i put the return value as "NO MATCH" but could easily be something else such as "".

Comment: YES!!! Thank you so much! You are amazing! If you're ever in Houston, TX, hit me up! I owe you a beer!!! hahahahah

Thank you so much.This is exactly what I needed. I hope the range guys don't need more added to this sheet... but if they do, and I can't figure it out, I know where to go for help! ;)

Comment: No worries.  Pleased to help.